# Using PHPMailer in own php file within Typo3

Tags: php, typo3, phpmailer

I want to use the PHPMailer Class within my own php file within Typo3.
To do so I have done following:

```
require 'fileadmin/templates/main/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->setLanguage('de');
$mail->From = "XX@XXX.de";
$mail->FromName = "XXX";
$mail->addAddress($email);
$mail->addAddress("YYY@YYY.de");
$mail->addReplyTo('XX@XXX.de', 'XXX');
$mail->WordWrap = 50;
if($lang == "de")
{
    $mail->Subject = "XXX";
    $mail->Body    = nl2br($text_de);
    $mail->AltBody = nl2br($text_de);
}
else {
    $mail->Subject = "XXX";
    $mail->Body    = nl2br($text_en);
    $mail->AltBody = nl2br($text_en);
}

$mail->send();
```

Outside of Typo3 this works without any problems.
Typo3 Version is 4.5.32.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't actually say what the problem is. You should be using the autoloader.

Answer (score 0):

PHPMailer uses its own Autoloader. 
Including it in other Frameworks often results in problems with colliding Autloaders.

Try giving the two PHPMailer Files their own namespace with

```
namespace PHPMailer;
```

in the first line.

Then change this

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
```

to

```
$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
```

Comment: Trying this results in "Uncaught TYPO3 Exception"
Function 'PHPMailerAutoload' not found (function 'PHPMailerAutoload' not found or invalid function name) 

LogicException thrown in file
/srv/www/htdocs/fileadmin/templates/main/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php in line 37.

This line is:
spl_autoload_register('PHPMailerAutoload', true, true);

Comment: change this line to

spl_autoload_register('PHPMailer\PHPMailerAutoload', true, true);